# MySQL query for getting latest record for each entry from table with 10 million rows

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

Use Case:

I have table, lets say: "**manufacturer**"

```
manuf_code  manuf_display_name  record_status  record_timestamp  

----------  -------------------  ------------  ----------------
M000001      Sam                      N        2017-09-13 12:13:16      
M000002      JII                      N        2017-09-13 15:13:15      
M000002      JII                      U        2017-09-13 17:16:35      
M000003      Sun                      N        2017-09-13 18:54:16      
M000004      NG-Graphics              N        2017-09-13 19:13:15
M000004      NG-Graphics              U        2017-09-14 20:16:50 
M000004      NG-Graphics              U        2017-09-14 09:13:25 
M000005      HewNett                  N        2017-09-15 10:24:19     
M000006      HewNett                  N        2017-09-15 10:24:19  
M000007      HewNett                  N        2017-09-15 10:24:19  
M000007      HewNett                  U        2017-09-15 15:10:16 
M000007      HewNett                  U        2017-09-17 21:35:19 
M000007      HewNett                  U        2017-09-17 21:37:26
```

- When user creates a new manufacturer, the details sits in the table with *record_status* as '**N**'.
- When user updates the existing manufacturer, the row for that Manufacturer ID gets updated with *record_status* as '**U**'

Now there can be around 7-10 Million such entries with each manufacturer having:

- A single entry with status as '**N**'
- Multiple entries with status as '**U**'

Requirement: I need to fetch the latest entry for each manufacturer.

My query:

```
SELECT m.manuf_code
     , m.manuf_display_name
     , m.record_timestamp
     , m.record_status 
  FROM manufacturers m 
  JOIN
     ( SELECT manuf_code
           , MAX(record_timestamp) AS maxdate 
        FROM manufacturers 
           WHERE record_status = 'N' OR record_status = 'U' 
         GROUP 
          BY manuf_code) mn
    ON m.manuf_code = mn.manuf_code 
   AND m.record_timestamp = mn.maxdate
```

I preferred Join sub query as former was faster, in fetching around 7 Million Data.

But, I need to get this work more fast, as after I fetch this many data I may even have to INSERT the same data in some table with a new record_status.

Please suggest.

EDIT:

```
CREATE TABLE `manufacturers` (
  `manuf_code` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `record_status` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `manuf_display_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `record_timestamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`manuf_code`, `record_update_timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

EXPLANATION:

New entry will have status --> 'N'
Update of an existing entry will have status --> 'U'
That's it. Query should get latest for this much.

Another case, specific to requirement is, we fetch all the latest entries per record and the make the status as 'L' and INSERT them again

Comment: An index on record_status and manuf_code will help you out using the same query

Comment: Pls do not use random product and language tags! Pls share the results of the explsin aling with what indexes you have on the table. Also, can the status be anything else than N or U?

Comment: @Shadow Sorry for tags. Also, I am not using any index as of now.
I am not very familiar with using indexes (would be helpful you can point me to the right direction).

Comment: Do you have to select these 7 million records every time, or you are working with one manuf_code at a time?

Comment: @Shadow Also, the status is N or U while creating or updating data.
But, I once I fetch all the latest record, I am planning to make the status as 'L' as Live and ready. So another 10 Million entry in the table.

Comment: @cha all 7 Million record at once.

Comment: Please read my reply to Shadow.. I need to make status for all the fetched latest record as 'L' and the INSERT them again.

Comment: Presumably status can be something other than n or u (or L) ?

Comment: Where's the EXPLAIN? We also need to see SHOW CREATE TABLE manufacturers

Comment: I have added the Table.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate question is addressed first, then an alternative design is discussed:

**Groupwise Max**

This is a "groupwise max" problem.  For multi-million row tables, the typical queries are rather slow, all involving full table scans.  To improve on that, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

**History vs Current**

Another approach is to keep 2 tables:

- `History` of actions; this is what you currently have.  It is mostly `INSERTed` into.
- `Current` status for each item.  This would be trivial to fetch from.  It is mostly `UPDATEd`.  Or, better yet, `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...` so that new items can be inserted without extra statements.

You say "When user creates / updates ...".  How is this being performed?   I hope they are not issuing SQL statements.  I suggest you consider some subroutine (in client code) or Stored Procedure (in MySQL).  That way, you can hide the details of the two tables, etc, from the user.

**Bulk Upload**

You say lots of inserts/updates/etc are provide en masse?  Load such into a temporary table (either `CREATE TEMPORARY` or a permanent table that you `TRUNCATE` and reuse`).  Then write a relatively small number of SQL statements to combine the data to put into`Current`and shovel (mostly intact) into`History`.

Comment: 1. Keeping History table is not an option.
2. Manufacturers are created through bulk upload of file. (status - 'N')
3. A manufacturer can be updated through UI, which I will save in DB.(status - 'U').
4. INSERT on DUPLICATE KEY... I suggested, but looks like we REALLY need the information of each manufacturer when created and if updated anytime.

Comment: I added a suggestion about bulk upload.